# React: how to compare path with params witn concrete path

Tags: reactjs, path, routes, comparison

I have 2 logical parts of App with different paths, and I need to know where to user go. I do it like this:

```
this.props.history.listen((location, action) =>
    {
        if (action === "PUSH")
        {
            const { modeType } = this.props;

            if ((modeType === first && secondPathes.includes(location.pathname))
                || (modeType === second && firstPathes.includes(location.pathname)))
            {
                // some logic
            }
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work for paths with params: `"/customers/1/profile" != "/customers/:id/profile"`. How can I do correct comparison of pathes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use [matchPath](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath) from `react-router`.

```
matchPath("/customers/3/profile", { path: "/customers/:id/profile" })
```

and use `some` instead of `includes`.